# What information can we collect from the service bus?

Tags: c#-4.0, azure, servicebus

My problem is a simple one. I'm working on a project that uses the service bus from Microsoft Azure to send messages asynchronously between different modules on different virtual machines. And a lot of messages are sent through this bus, so we want to have some indicators about it's performance and other usage information. Why? Because when everything is working, users are happy. When the system is slow, we want to show the user some interesting graphs, statistics, meters and other gadgets to give them an indication if there's a problem within Azure or with something else. And to do this, I need data about the usage of the Azure service bus.
So, which Azure API's are available to display what kind of (diagnostic) information about the service bus?

(Users should have no access to Azure itself! They should just see some performance data to re-assure them Azure is working fine. Or else I could look at it and discover some problem with it, fix it and then make users happy again.)

To elaborate what I'm looking for, the Azure website has some nice chart when you click the Monitor of the Azure bus showing you overviews of the number of incoming messages, the number of errors and their types, size information and the number of succesful operations, all based on a specified period. It would be nice if I could receive this data within my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entity metrics API will give you the exact data the portal is using:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn163589.aspx

Here's a Subscribe! episode I recorded with Rajat on the topic http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Subscribe/Service-Bus-Namespace-Management-and-Analytics

Answer (score 0):

I've spent quite some time to make the entity metrics API work, so I decided to share the results.

Here is a full C# code example of how to consume those API: 
[github repository](https://github.com/mikhailshilkov/ServiceBusEntityMetrics).

It's a small library which wraps the HTTP request into strongly typed .NET classes. You can also grab it from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MikhailIo.ServiceBusEntityMetrics/).

Finally, here is my [blog post](http://mikhail.io/2017/03/azure-service-bus-entity-metrics-dotnet-apis/) with the walkthrough.